# Was there a planned resolution for Almost Human?

Tags: almost-human

The answer to this question is usually, no - TV writers are desperately pounding out the next script in advance of the next episode, so not much time to plot out long plotlines (LOST, I'm looking in your direction).

But this show's cancellation was a real bummer...have the producers / writers / anybody talked about what the plan was going to be?

Comment: Indeed - I was very sad to see it cancelled. This was one of the best shows on TV. It reminded me of the awesome sci-fi shows on TV back in the 90's - very nostalgic...

Comment: [The creator claims a 5-year plan existed for the show](http://collider.com/j-h-wyman-almost-human-interview/), but the creators of Lost also claimed at the beginning that they had a 6-year plan before starting...

Answer (score 2):

As it stands, Season 1 ends on a high note with Kennex and Dorian becoming friends and Kennex accepting him as his partner. It is so much better an ending for a series than a cliff hanger which will never be resolved.

If you are asking what would have likely been in Season 2 (or later seasons)? Because that would *probably* have been:

> Kennex's not entirely recovered memories of his ex-girlfriend's involvement with inSyndicate? Saving it for Season 2.
>
> Anything else having to do with inSyndicate, its plans and the ill-fated mission that cost Kennex his leg? Saving it for Season 2.
>
> Dorian's "memories" and how he got them? Season 2.
>
> That roboticist played by John Larroquette going over the Wall* and taking the components to build an android army with him? Season 2. - [ref](http://www.zap2it.com/blogs/almost_human_season_1_finale_life_goes_on_for_kennex_and_dorian_will_it_for_the_show-2014-03)

Comment: Yeah, the memories was a big one for me. I suspect that he had the memories of an actual human being that had died, and that's why he was "special".

Comment: Also, hopefully there would have been more about the Wall's other side, and _why_ exactly the Wall is there - there was too much made of how important the fortified division is, for that to not play a part. That's the burningest question the show left in my mind, tbh.